# Similarties profiles retrieval from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we have 1 million documents indexed in elasticsearch with name,id,skills,etc like a form a resume.

If I search for kartheek in the search box it will retrieve some results right and I found kartheek resume and I have clicked and view the resume.

Once I will view the resume I need to view the similar profiles based on the viewed resume.

Is it possible in elasticsearch

1.I learned about More Like This Query but we need to give input paramter i.e 'LIKE'.
2.I have seen this link 
http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/document-similarity-analysis-using-elasticsearch-and-python

Please any can give me ideas regarding the above mentioned request.

Thanks

Kartheek Gummaluri

Comment: Is stopping your cluster (thus downtime) for a while an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

To go from 1.x to 2.x you need to do what is known as a full cluster restart upgrade, you wont lose data in this case, here are the relevant steps laid out well from the docs:

[Elastic Search Upgrade Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-upgrade.html)